# REF: Communications engineering, call arrival rate, poisson

Tags: discussion

Kortuk commented:

> Communication theory has always been considered acceptable here. This
>   is definitely a boundary question, but I think one that is still on
>   topic. If you would like to continue discussion of it @JonnyBoats ask
>   on meta. Right now as a moderator I am not going to take action as I
>   support this as on topic, at its heart all communication theory is
>   applied statistics. – Kortuk♦ 8 hours ago

I response to my comment that stats.stacmexchange "may be a better place for this question."

I had not flagged or voted to close the question, simply posted the comment. It was not trying to imply that the question was off topic; merely that it *might* get a good answer on the other site.

My primary reason for posting here on meta is to ask when it is appropriate to suggest another stack site? In particular now that there are so many sites it seems that there is often an overlap so that a question could be on topic for more than one site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may have miss-communicated some. You can suggest all day long, I have no issue with it, even promote it, but your comment received upvotes and I had received flags. I wanted to post my view and suggest that if you felt the question was strongly off topic to suggest it on meta.

Please, do take the time to guide members in ways they can improve the answers they receive. I was stating that I would not take mod action to move the question so that others would hopefully not continue flagging their question.